# Правила urlManager в Yii

Tags: yii, url, rules

Как создать правилa в urlManager на фреймворке Yii?

```
site.com/blog/detail?url=example => site.com/blog/example
```

или:

```
site.com/blog/detail/example
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' =>  '<controller>/<action>',
```